# Spring boot JPA nativeQuery Incorrect syntax near @P0

Tags: java, sql, spring, hibernate, jpa

I am trying to run the following query from a spring boot app using Hibernate, and the problem is that in the query I need to pass the path variable from the method.

```java
@Query(
   value = "INSERT INTO dbo.images (imageblob)(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK ?, SINGLE_BLOB) imageblol) SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);",
   nativeQuery = true)
Integer insertImage(String path);
```

the error I am getting is

```
com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '@P0'.
```

If I write the path manually it will work

```java
@Query(
   value = "INSERT INTO dbo.images (imageblob)(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK 'C:\\pic\\NORMAL2-IM-1257-0001.jpeg', SINGLE_BLOB) imageblol) SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);",
   nativeQuery = true)
Integer insertImage(String path);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

'@P0' is your RowCountToDisplay parameter ... Maybe try to place parenthesis around the argument

```
INSERT INTO dbo.images (imageblob)(SELECT * FROM OPENROWSET (BULK (?), SINGLE_BLOB) imageblol) SELECT CAST(scope_identity() AS int);"
             , nativeQuery = true)
```

Comment: this will return com.microsoft.sqlserver.jdbc.SQLServerException: Incorrect syntax near '('.

Comment: try changing dialect

Comment: actually, this was the issue.  It turns out that Hibernate does not support all the dialects